# pgAdmin 4. Unable to connect to server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I had a postgreSQL server/database working in a local area network in Windows. To have access to it through Ethernet I changed the IP in the router settings. Everything was fine. But when I came today to the office, I could not have connected to the server. Moreover, I cannot even create a localhost server on that PC. The error is "Unable to connect to server:" and nothing else. When I turn off the postgres in services it specifies the error with TCP/IP, port, etc. But not when the service is on. When connecting to the server, the pgAdmin asks for the postgres password. Endlessly, thou the password is printed correctly and the METHOD is set to trust. The reinstallation did not help.
What does this error mean? And what is the cure?

Comment: Some numbers: the version of the postgreSQL is 10, pgAdmin 4. I have installed posgreSQL 14 as well and managed to create a new server with the PC's IP as host. But after the relaunch of the service, I cannot connect to it or create a new one.

Comment: What version of pgAdmin4?

Comment: Do not remember the versions of previous pgAdmins uninstalled, now, it's 6.1 (installed with PostgreSQL 14)

Comment: There was a pgAdmin4 bug a while ago that lead to incomplete error messages, but 6.1 should be well beyond that.  But still, 6.3 is the current version.  I find `psql` a much simpler way to debug connections issues.

Comment: Thanks! I did not find what was the problem is, thou the issue is gone:

Comment: After deleting the postgreSQL 10, the logs in postgreSQL 14 showed (sorry for my liberal translation to English): "unsupported server version".

Comment: After installing the postgreSQL 10 back again and uninstalling 14, I could've created local servers.

Comment: The logs of work with the old "data" folder told me that the password of the postgres user is wrong. Though I really checked it several times.

Comment: So, I left the files in the root 'data' folder of the newly installed postgreSQL 10 but substituted only the folders inside it.

Comment: The problem of the postgres user password remained but this time I managed to evade it by changing method in the pg_hba to trust.